# Как программировать под Symbian?

Tags: symbian, delphi

Собственно вопрос заключается в том:

1. Какие библиотеки нужно скачать.
2. Откуда их можно скачать.
3. Как их подключить.
4. И возможно ли использовать старый код, например калькулятора, в будущей программе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на Delphi под симбу программировать не получится. Компилятор не умеет собирать под платформы отличные от x86.

Comment: Delphi XE2 уже умеет под x64 и OS X )

Answer (score 1):

Под Symbian можно программировать на qt, взять его можно здесь: qt.nokia.com, там можно скачать IDE Qt creator, в нем есть все нужные библиотеки, но использовать скорее всего придется С++, на счет того можно ли использовать делфи я не уверен.

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор умеет собирать под платформы отличные от x86 но к сожалению под Symbian нет.